# How to Restore deleted items of the sharepoint list from recycle bin using Item ID through Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Tried  with below Code but didn't working

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://server/sites/site
$site.RecycleBin.Restore($DeletedItem)

$DeletedItem = $ListItem.recycle()

ForEach ($deletedid in $DeletedItems)
{
    $site.RecycleBin.Restore($deletedid)
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving you an error? Are you trying to restore everything?

Comment: I am trying to restore only few(100) items which belongs to a particular  sharepoint list out of all  items(1000 mixed) in recycle bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you're wanting to restore everything in the recycle bin.

```
$Site = Get-SPSite http://server/sites/site

#Get All Recycle bin items
$DeletedItems = $Site.RecycleBin

if($DeletedItems)
{
 foreach($Item in $DeletedItems) 
 {
   if ($Item.DirName.Contains("YourListName"))
   {
     $Site.RecycleBin.restore($Item.ID)
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it is restoring all the items of the site instead of restoring items of a particular list of the site

Comment: Try the update I just made. It filters the directory name by using the name of your list.